# EMVA standard 1288 SNR formula (equation 11)

Tags: image-sensor, snr

I'm trying to understand equation 11 for Signal-to-Noise Ratio in EMVA standard 1288 Release Candidate 3.1:
http://www.emva.org/cms/upload/Standards/Stadard_1288/EMVA1288-3.1rc.pdf page 7.

Using equations 6 and 8 I arrive at something similar to eq 11. However for me there is no

[image: paper]

Instead I get
[image: me]

I have to say it makes more sense to me to find another noise term below instead of number of electrons.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have just substituted the statistics for shot noise back into the equation.
\$ \sigma_e^2 = \mu_e \$  and \$ \mu_e= \eta\mu_p    \$ i.e. # of electrons = QE * # photons and shot noise follows \$ \sqrt N \$ statistics.

Other than the different nomenclature (other than what I am used to that is) it is a good document and I recommend you conform to it's standards.

Comment: OK, I rest my case. It is late here. But they could have mentioned to use eq 7 too :)

Comment: You're not understanding what shot noise statistics are then.  remember that shot noise will be \$ \sqrt{ \sigma_e^2 }\$ eqn #7